# Yii resolving url as controller/action instead of executing the underlying script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, perl, yii

The code I'm mantaining right now uses Yii v1.0 and uber uploader to achieve file upload. It does so by calling uber uploaders perl script from a jquery.post inside a js file. Im using a godaddy linux virtual server with PHP Version 5.3.28

the perl script is finally getting called by ubr_file_upload.js in the line:

```
jQuery.post(this.path_to_link_script, data, function(){}, "script");
```

where path_to_link_script is `/scgi-bin/ubr_upload.pl`. This happens inside a js function called `linkUpload` which is called from the upload form in `fileUpload.php` when clicking the submit button:

```
<form id="<?php echo $PARMS[$i]['id'];?>
    _ubr_upload_form" name="<?php echo $PARMS[$i]['id'];?>
    _ubr_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
     action="#" onSubmit="return UU<?php echo $i?>.linkUpload();">`
```

Which is rendered by a yii widget in:

```
$this->render('fileUpload',array('PARMS'=>$this->_uberSettings->PARMS,
    'debug_ajax'=>$this->_uberSettings->INI['debug_ajax']));`
```

When users go to the form, select a file and click upload, I see the following error in chrome's console:

```
POST https://www.example.com/scgi-bin/ubr_upload.pl?upload_id=b5XXXXXXXXXbcc0
    404 (CHttpException)
```

(Xs added to mantain privacy)

Then, checking the Network tab, I see the following call failing after being called when pressing the submit button:

```
https://www.example.com/scgi-bin/ubr_upload.pl?upload_id=b5XXXXXXXXXbcc0
```

The response it gets is as following:

```
Page Not Found

Unable to resolve the request "scgi-bin/ubr_upload.pl".

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact support@example.com.
```

It looks as if Yii is trying to resolve the url instead of executing the script.

If I, however, visit that same url by hand (https://www.example.com/scgi-bin/ubr_upload.pl?upload_id=b5XXXXXXXXXbcc0), it executes the perl script correctly.

I am stuck. Completely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There could be many things wrong here. Do you have an .htaccess file - if so, please paste details. Also post your Urlmanager rules from the config/main.php file.

Comment: What do you mean by "...visit the same url by hand..."

Comment: "visit the same url by hand" would be a bad translation of opening that url in a browser instead of letting the js do an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was inside uber uploader's widget EuberUploaderWidget. The widget was re-declaring the TEMP_DIR with `$this->_uberSettings->TEMP_DIR = ...` using a hard-coded path (which of course was wrong after moving the whole installation to a new folder). 
I had not checked in there since I had already modified it in the model, plus Uber uploader did not give *any* error that would lead me to that direction, it was completely random that we ended up trying that.